# How can I correctly express in BNF this condition?

Tags: language-design, bnf

I am looking for a way to express the following types of conditions in BNF:

```
if(carFixed) { }

if(carFixed = true) {}

if(cars >= 4) { }

if(cars != 15) { }

if(cars < 3 && cars > 1) {}
```

Note:

1. `*` denotes `0` or more instances of something.
2. I have replaced normal BNF `::=` with `:`.

I presently am using the following code, and am not sure if it's correct:

```
conditionOperator: "=" | "!=" | "<=" | ">=" | "<" | ">" | "is";

logicalAndOperator: "&&";

condition: (booleanIdentifier ((conditionOperator booleanIdentifier)* (logicalAndOperator | logicalOrOperator) booleanIdentifer (conditionOperator booleanIdentifier)*)*);
```

Answer (score 1):

There are several approaches and they usually rely on the capabilities of the parser to indicate precedence and associativty. One that is typically used with recursive-descent parsers is to recreate the precedence of the operators by using the hierarchy provided by the bnf (or, in this case, pseudo-bnf) structure.

*(In the examples bellow, CONDITIONAL_OP are the likes of `<`, `!=` etc and LOGICAL_OP are `&&`, `||` etc)*

Something in the lines of:

```
    condition: logicalExpr
    logicalExpr: conditionalExpr (LOGICAL_OP conditionalExpr)*
    conditionalExpr: primary (CONDITIONAL_OP primary)*
    primary: NUMBER | IDENTIFIER | BOOLEAN_LITERAL | '(' condition ')'
```

The problem with the above solution is that the left-associativity of the operators is lost and requires special measures to restore it while parsing.

For parsers able to deal with left recursion, a more 'correct' notation could be:

```
    condition: logicalExpr
    logicalExpr: logicalExpr LOGICAL_OP conditionalExpr
               | conditionalExpr
    conditionalExpr: conditionalExpr CONDITIONAL_OP primary
                   | primary
    primary: NUMBER | IDENTIFIER | BOOLEAN_LITERAL | '(' condition ')'
```

Finally, some parsers allow a special notation to indicate precedence and associativity. Something like (note that this is a completely invented syntax):

```
    %LEFT LOGICAL_OP
    %LEFT CONDITIONAL_OP 
    condition: condition CONDITIONAL_OP condition
             | condition LOGICAL_OP condition
             | '(' condition ')'
             | NUMBER
             | IDENTIFIER
             | BOOLEAN_LITERAL
```

Hope this points you the right direction.